# ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Spoiler alert**: this is **NOW** a question, so apologies to anyone that read it purely as a discursive topic :)

*Anyway*, I was doing a little research today re adding routes via javascript when i thought that a bit of google research wouldn't hurt. Basically, my aim was to do away with the following type of construct within my views:

[image]

and replace it with something akin to:

[image]

well, i lucked out a little today after finding this fantastic article (which isn't mine nor do i have any affiliation other than respect for the piece of work):

http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx

this really has been a missing link (or so i thought) for me when dealing with routes via javascript. However, the 2nd code example is misleading and actually won't produce what the example leads on. Can anyone suggest a fix for this and/or an alternative solution to allow this fluent convention of js routes within mvc views??

cheers...

**[edit]** - question edited 22:16 GMT to explore deeper options on this topic, plus changed title (removed **OT** portion).

Comment: **Spoiler Alert**: Stack Overflow is for questions.

Comment: Nathan -yup, appreciated. really just wanted to add this little **OT** nugget to the mix. tail between legs  - ouch/touche etc :) !!

Comment: Oh look someone's plugging my little pet project :D

Comment: @zowens - yes, i couldn't find anywhere else on here to 'plug' it (short of asking a question and saying -'maybe this might work'??). it's fantastic. i really appreciate your efforts on that one - kudos

Comment: @jim I do have a suggestion to form this into a question... Edit the question to ask why the 2nd code example is misleading and actually won't produce what the example leads on (just realized I screwed up the code on my blog... oops)

Comment: @zowens - ok, will now steamroll your efforts :-) (joke!)

Comment: @jim @zowens This content does not belong on Stack Overflow. This is not a discussion board. OT in the topic or not, this not an appropriate venue for this post.

Comment: @Nathan-Taylor Exactly... that's why I suggested a way to form this into a question...

Comment: @ALL - question re-jigged to put that (l)awful @zowens on the spot :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the question is why the second code example won't work as expected. Here's the answer, post currently doesn't return anything. This is an example of a certain developer not looking at the details of the code. When you use homePageUrl, the value will be undefined.

To actually get the home page URL, you'd do the following:

```
$.routeManager.action({controller:'Home', action:'Index'}).toUrl()
```

So, the moral of the story is that the code is a bit broken. The post action SHOULD return an object where you can put "toUrl()" right after the post is performed, like this:

```
$.routeManager.action({controller:'Home', action:'Index'})
              .post(function(data){ alert(data); })
              .toUrl();
```

I'll be fixing this bug in a bit!

Comment: +1 - for a humble response ;). plus a wee tick as it's the answer - yeah... thanks!!

Comment: It's fixed now... I can't believe I put that in my blog post. I need to be a bit more careful!

Comment: zack - even the 'best' of us can fall on our swords :-). will check out the update later and thanks again.